# scrapy start_urls from txt file

Tags: python, scrapy

i have around 100K urls to scrape so i want to read them from a txt file
here is the code

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class ConadstoresSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'conadstores'
    headers = {'user_agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1207.1 Safari/537.1"}
    allowed_domains = ['conad.it']
    #start_urls = ['http://www.conad.it/ricerca-negozi/negozio.002781.html','https://www.conad.it/ricerca-negozi/negozio.006804.html']
    #start_urls = [l.strip() for l in open("/Users/macbook/PycharmProjects/conad/conad/conadlinks.txt").readlines()]
    #f = open("/Users/macbook/PycharmProjects/conad/conad/conadlinks.txt")
    #start_urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]
    #f.close()

    with open('/Users/macbook/PycharmProjects/conad/conad/conadlinks.txt') as file:
        start_urls = [line.strip() for line in file]


    def start_request(self):
        request = Request(url = self.start_urls, callback=self.parse)
        yield request

    def parse(self, response):
        yield {
            'address' : response.css('.address-oswald::text').extract(),
            'phone' : response.css('span.phone::text').extract(),

        }
```

but i keep on getting this error

2021-12-08 13:27:48 [scrapy.core.engine] ERROR: Error while obtaining start requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/macbook/PycharmProjects/conad/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 127, in _next_request
request = next(slot.start_requests)
File "/Users/macbook/PycharmProjects/conad/conad/conad/middlewares.py", line 52, in process_start_requests
for r in start_requests:
File "/Users/macbook/PycharmProjects/conad/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/**init**.py", line 83, in start_requests
yield Request(url, dont_filter=True)
File "/Users/macbook/PycharmProjects/conad/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scrapy/http/request/**init**.py", line 25, in **init**
self._set_url(url)
File "/Users/macbook/PycharmProjects/conad/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scrapy/http/request/**init**.py", line 62, in _set_url
raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)
ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: %7B%5Crtf1%5Cansi%5Cansicpg1252%5Ccocoartf2580

any idea?
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can override the start_urls logic in spider's start_requests() method

this is simple way to extract your data

```
import scrapy


class ConadstoresSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'conadstores'

    def start_requests(self):
        # read file data (you can use different logic for extract URLS from text files)
        a_file = open("/Users/macbook/PycharmProjects/conad/conad/conadlinks.txt")
        file_contents = a_file.read()
        contents_split = file_contents.splitlines()
        # extract urls from text file and store in list
        for url in contents_split:
            # send request to extracted URL.
            yield scrapy.Request(url)

    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        yield {
            'address': response.css('.address-oswald::text').extract(),
            'phone': response.css('span.phone::text').extract(),

        }
```

**you can use different file reading logic but make sure that it's return url list.**

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, but im still getting the error which ends like  File "/Users/macbook/PycharmProjects/conad/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py", line 62, in _set_url
    raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)

Comment: ok, it looks like the txt file was somehow broken! i created a new csv and now works fine thanks a lot!

Comment: yes happy coding